# Stored procedure parameter error

Tags: stored-procedures

I have created a simple stored procedure like this:

```
Alter Proc dbo.s5 
(
  @id int = 14,
  @Salary int output
)
As
Begin
  --Declare @Salary int
  set @Salary = (select Salary
                 from dbo.EmpInf
                 where EmpId = @id)
  print @Salary
  --Return @Salary
End
```

During execution of this stored procedure, I get this error:

> *Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure s5, Line 0
>
>   Procedure or function 's5' expects parameter '@Salary', which was not supplied.*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the @Salary variable as input variable to your stored proc even though it is marked as an output parameter.

```
exec dbo.s5 @id, @salary
```

As can be read in the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Input values can also be specified for OUTPUT parameters when the stored procedure is executed. This allows the stored procedure to receive a value from the calling program, change it or perform operations with it, then return the new value to the calling program. ... This is often referred to as "pass-by-reference capability.

Comment: Returning Data by Using OUTPUT Parameters:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Ma'am i have executed the sp by providing Exec dbo.s5 14,5. now it executes correctly.but what is a point of providing the Output variable a value, if we are marking as Output.

Comment: If you declare the @Salary variable before you execute your stored procedure and print it after you have executed it, the variable will contain the OUTPUT value specified in the stored proc. You can then use this variable's value in your server side code or where ever you intend to use it.  NOTE: I have updated my answer to include quoted text from above link explaining it.

Comment: Yeah, i understand a steps of working. But why the Sql has made this work like this, is still a question. Thanks @kleinkie